# Properties matrix $A^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let be $A$ a matrix such that $A^2=I$. According my book the $A$'eigenvalues are $-1$ and $+1$?. but, For me is only $+1$, this because $A = \sqrt{I} = I$.

Comment: The *possible* eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Do you also assert that $x^2=1$ has only the solution $x=\sqrt{1} = 1$?

Comment: understand, ... and How I will be able to represent $A := \sum_{1\le k\le n}\lambda_k P_k$? What's are the $P_k$? where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues and $P_k$ are projections

Comment: for every matix that A^-1=A this will happen

Answer (score 6):

Look at $A=-I$: what is its square, and what are its eigenvalues?

Comment: understand, ... and How I will be able to represent $A := \sum_{1\le k\le n}\lambda_k P_k$? What's are the $P_k$? where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues and $P_k$ are projections

Comment: then only $I$ and $-I$ satisfy $A^2=I$?

Comment: No. See above, Andreas Caranti's example, for instance; more generally, a lot of matrices have this property.

Comment: ok, and this question -- How I will be able to represent $A := \sum_{1\le k\le n}\lambda_k P_k$ What's are the $P_k$? where $\lambda k$ are the eigenvalues and $P_k$ are projections

Comment: Look at "Diagonalization" and "Triangularisability" in your textbook -- this might provide some insight.

Answer (score 5):

Your use of the square root of a matrix does not quite work.

Consider that all matrices
$$
A =
\frac{1}{ad-bc} \,
\begin{bmatrix}
cd - ab & d^{2} - b^{2}\\
a^{2} - c^{2} & ab - c d
\end{bmatrix},
$$
for $ad - b c \ne 0$,
have $A^{2} = I$

Comment: understand, ... and How I will be able to represent $A := \sum_{1\le k\le n}\lambda_k P_k$? What's are the $P_k$? where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues and $P_k$ are projections

Comment: Why "all matrices" are limited by two dimensions?

Comment: two dimensions? I don't understand your question

Comment: Val seems to be interpreting Andreas' hint as a description of *all* such matrices that satisfy the given condition. Clearly, Andreas is providing insight into the general case with a simple example.

Comment: How do you extend it to 3 dimensions?

Comment: @Val, I simply took all conjugates of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, which has eigenvalues $1, -1$. This can be imitated in higher dimensions, although of course formulas become more complicated.